# How can I apply different fonts to different scripts across Ubuntu?

Tags: fonts, language-support, system-settings

The default font does not support the Devanagiri script which is used to write Hindi. Even so Hindi **file-names** in Nautilus and **bookmarks** in Firefox display fine. I am guessing it defaults to using Lohit-Hindi typeface.

I want to use the "Noto Sans Devanagiri" typeface instead. How can I accomplish this?

Please note that I do not want the system UI to support the Hindi language, which I am aware can be done via System Settings by adding support for preferred language. I just want to be able to assign a system-wide typeface to be used for all text that falls in the Devanagiri code-point.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the *fonts-noto* package, if you haven't already done so. If that's not sufficient, you can create a file along these lines:

```
$ cat /etc/fonts/conf.d/65-fonts-noto-devanagari.conf
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
    <alias>
        <family>sans-serif</family>
        <prefer>
            <family>Noto Sans Devanagari</family>
        </prefer>
    </alias>
    <alias>
        <family>monospace</family>
        <prefer>
            <family>Noto Sans Devanagari</family>
        </prefer>
    </alias>
</fontconfig>
```